# Multiword synonyms with Solr and Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, search, solr, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a synonyms.txt file with content as below

```
car accessories, gadi marmat
```

and I am indexing **car accessories** as a single token so that it will expand to **car accessories** and **gadi marmat**.

i want the whole synonyms to match so that when query for **gadi marmat**, the record with **car accessories** to be returned.

I am using shingle filter factory to expand query so that when searching for **gadi marmat**, it will be expanded to **gadi**, **gadi marmat** and **marmat**, and since **gadi marmat** is queried as a single token, it should have matched **car accessories** and returned result but this is not the case, but when i search for **car accessories**, it is returning result. So must be prblm with indexing synonyms that have multiple words.

Please suggest.

Comment: note : expand is set to true.

Comment: Have you tried using `/admin/analysis.jsp` to see that the token expansion is functioning as you expect?

Answer (score 3):

synonym file is use only to change a word that are you searching.
so if you write

car accessories => gadi marmat

when a compiler matching on "car accessories", it try to matching on "gadi marmat"

it works like a single token

you can get good results mixing analyzer elements like that

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "integram",
tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
filters = {
     @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
     @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class, params = {
         @Parameter(name = "words", value = "lucene/dictionary/stopwords.txt"),
         @Parameter(name = "ignoreCase", value = "true"),
         @Parameter(name = "enablePositionIncrements", value = "true")
     }),
     @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
            @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English")
     }),
     @TokenFilterDef(factory = SynonymFilterFactory.class, params = {
         @Parameter(name = "synonyms", value = "lucene/dictionary/synonyms.txt"),
         @Parameter(name = "expand", value = "false")
     }),
     @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
            @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English")
     })
})
```

Comment: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000114: Could not load resource: 'lucene/dictionary/synonyms.txt'. I can't load the synonyms or stopwords. Are these files that I need to download? I thought they would ship with this functionality in Maven.