# Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000114: Could not load resource: 'synonyms.txt'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, solr, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate search in spring boot for the first time and trying to define my own german synonyms and I am using this code:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "edgeNgram",
            tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class),
            filters = {
                    @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class), // Replace accented characeters by their simpler counterpart (è => e, etc.)
                    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class), // Lowercase all characters
                    @TokenFilterDef(
                            factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class, // Generate prefix tokens
                            params = {
                                    @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "2"),
                                    @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "4")
                            }
                    ),
                    @TokenFilterDef(
                            factory = SynonymFilterFactory.class,
                            params = {
                                    @Parameter(name = "ignoreCase", value = "true"),
                                    @Parameter(name = "expand", value = "true"),
                                    @Parameter(name = "synonyms", value = "synonyms.txt"),
                            })

            })
```

when I use "factory = SynonymFilterFactory.class" and define my "synonyms.txt" file I get the error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000114: Could not load resource: 'synonyms.txt'
```

I am new to spring boot and will appreciate any help!
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
                                    @Parameter(name = "synonyms", value = "synonyms.txt")
```

Means you're asking Hibernate Search to load a file named `synonyms.txt` from your classpath, and extract the list of synonyms from there.

If you don't have a file named `synonyms.txt` at the root of your classpath, you'll get this exception.

Add the file and everything should be back in order.

See the javadoc of `org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SolrSynonymParser` for an explanation of the format of this file.

Comment: Exactly, when I ask Hibernate to load the "synonyms.txt" file I get this error. this "synonyms.txt" file is already at the same root as my code. I even tried to give the complete path for my "synonyms.txt" file but it did not work out. actually what I am trying to do is to follow your answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49444093/14240536) not for wordnet but for my own synonyms. and I think someone else have the same problem on (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12855718/14240536) -> the comment on this answer

Comment: "at the same root as my code" => The file shouldn't be in `src/main/java`, it should be in `src/main/resources`. I'm not sure what will happen if you put it in `src/main/java`, I've never tried that. If this still doesn't work, please create a reproducer based on [this project](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/search/hibernate-search-5/lucene) so I can have a look.

Comment: You should not use `src/main/resources/synonyms.txt` in your analyzer definition. Just `synonyms.txt`.

Comment: can I ask you one more question? Now there is no Errors when I refer to my "synonyms.txt" file but when I try to use the synonyms file I realized that hibernate search is not catching the synonyms. For example: in my "synonyms.txt" file I have   universe , cosmos  and in my database I have the word "cosmos" but when I search for "universe" I do not get "cosmos" as a search result ("expand" is set to "true" in my code)

Comment: You put the synonyms filter after the edgeNGram filter. The edgeNGram filter will turn "universe" into ["u", "un", "uni", "univ"] and then the synonym filter will not have a synonym for any of these tokens. I'd recommend switching the two filter: first the synonym filter, then the edgengram filter.